# Python: Passing an object instance from one function to another?

Tags: python, django, function, class, oop

I'm having trouble with passing a value from one script to another, trying to take it a step at a time but the big picture would be to print the value `obj1.get_predval` to my Django view and wait for the users' input.

`active_learner.obj1.get_predval` in my beta.py script doesn't work, it just prints out the initial value which makes sense because it's not running the main.py but I'm not sure how I'd pass the value of `obj1.set_predval(machine_prediction)` from main.py. It properly outputs the `obj1.get_predval` in the main.py script.

I'm assuming I have a fundamental misunderstanding, for now, all I'm trying to return is the value of `obj1.get_predval` in function `beta.py`, when it gets to the line return value and wait for user input then continue.

`main.py` script below

```
obj1 = MachinePred()
def main():
    model = load_model('model_new.h5')
    DATAFILE = "c_user_model_data100000.csv"
    dataset = loadtxt(DATAFILE, delimiter=",")
    X_pool, Y = dataset[:, 0:5], dataset[:, 5:]
    sc_x, sc_y = StandardScaler(), StandardScaler()
    X_pool, Y = sc_x.fit_transform(X_pool), sc_y.fit_transform(Y)

    learner = ActiveLearner(
        estimator = model,   
        query_strategy = uncertainty_sampling
    )

    for i in range(3):
        query_idx, query_inst = learner.query(X_pool)
        print("The machine queried:\n{}\nat index {}".format(
            sc_x.inverse_transform(query_inst),
            query_idx
            )
        )

        machine_prediction = learner.predict(X_pool[query_idx])
        obj1.set_predval(machine_prediction)
        print("predvalue:", (obj1.get_predval()))
        ratings = []
        cc_factor = ["delay", "speed", "missing_words", "paraphrasing"]
        for f in cc_factor:
            user_answer = input("How would you rate the quality of {} between [1-5]: ".format(f))
            ratings.append(user_answer)
        print(ratings, np.array([ratings]).reshape(1,-1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`beta.py`
This is the script I'm trying to pass the value to below

```
import active_learner
print(A is: ", active_learner.obj1.get_predval)
```

`mac.py` Simple python script using the get and set methods below.

```
class MachinePred:
    predval = 0  # Default value of the 'x' configuration setting

    def __init__(self):
        self.predval = 0

    def set_predval(self, val):
        self.predval = val

    def get_predval(self):
        return self.predval
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this was very simple, from my understanding it could be done using generator-based coroutines or splitting it into two functions inside a class and use an OO design. The coroutine method would use"yield" which would force exit the function returning the value then re-enter the function but this would limit your ability to use non-generator based coroutines which I did need to await input from my front end.

Using a class though you could put the active learner model and data in an "**init** method" then split from the `machine_prediction = learner.predict(X_pool[query_idx])` for the first function after returning the values and perform the rest in a second function.